# Как можно отфильтровать массив состоящий из объектов по двум свойствам

Tags: javascript, foreach

Помогите пожалуйста, отфильтровать массив состоящий из объектов. Задумка такая что кастомная функция filter должна вернуть массив с объектами у которых свойство name будет оригинальное, а свойство price минимальное

Мой код:

```js
const items = [ 
    {name: 'Молоко', price: 90},
    {name: 'Хлеб', price: 80},
    {name: 'Кефир', price: 90},
    {name: 'Молоко', price: 80},
    {name: 'Хлеб', price: 70},
    {name: 'Кефир', price: 80}
]

const filter = ( ) => items.forEach((element)=>{
    let result = [{name: null, price: 100}]

        for( resultItem of result){

            if( element.name != resultItem.name && element.price < resultItem.price ){
                
                result.push(element)
            }
        }
    return result
})

console.log(filter(items))
```

Comment: Если вы думаете, что превосходно описали свою проблему - то это не так

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста, отфильтровать массив состоящий из объектов.
Задумка такая что кастомная функция  filter должна вернуть массив с объектами у которых свойство name будет оригинальное, а свойство price минимальное

Comment: то есть должно быть: молоко-80, хлеб-70,кефир-80 - так?  А вот это `[{name: null, price: 100}]` имеет значение какое-либо?

Comment: Да именно так и хотелось бы [{молоко-80}, {хлеб-70},{кефир-80} ],
этот костыль с максимальным значением я из начально вставил что бы первый элемент мог условие if  пройти

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная идея в том, что мы создаём дополнительный словарь и для каждого элемента смотрим:

- Там есть элемент с именем данного элемента? Если нет то просто добавлем элемент и идём дальше
- Там есть элемент с именем данного элемента и его цена больше чем цена того что на очереди? Если да то заменяем значение и идём дальше
- В любом другом случае просто идём дальше

Ну и собственно сам код:

```js
const items = [ 
    {name: 'Молоко', price: 90},
    {name: 'Хлеб', price: 80},
    {name: 'Кефир', price: 90},
    {name: 'Молоко', price: 80},
    {name: 'Хлеб', price: 70},
    {name: 'Кефир', price: 80}
]

const filter = (array) => {
  const arrayMap = array.reduce((map, item) => {
    
    if (!map.has(item.name) || map.get(item.name) > item.price) {
    
      map.set(item.name, item.price);
    
    }
    
    return map;
    
  }, new Map());
  
  return [...arrayMap].map(item => ({name: item[0], price: item[1]}));
}

console.log(filter(items))
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, за идею и код